# location.reload re-send post

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I implemented a timeout every 5 seconds to run `location.reload()` but on the pages I have some forms that send some post to mongoDB and once I do it, it will redirect me back to the page for the updates to be visible. The issue is that once is redirected the `location.reload()` will re send the post and create a new record in MongoDB. is there a way to avoid this?

This is an example of my code:

orders.js

```
...
if(ActionDOM == 'accept'){
        FinalOrder.findOneAndUpdate({'_id':orderId},{
            "$set": {
                'orderStat':1,
                'last_update':Date.now()
            }
        }).then(order => {
            UpdateItem.aggregate([
                {
                    $group:{
                        _id:'a',
                        minNum:{
                            $max:'$idUpdate'
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]).then(u =>{
                var idUpdate = (u.length==0)?1:u[0].minNum+1
                const update = new UpdateItem({
                    idUpdate,
                    idUser:req.user._id,
                    idOrder:orderId,
                    orderStat:1
                })
                update.save().then(o =>{
                    Promise.all([mongoQueries.activeOrders(req.user._id.toString()),mongoQueries.menuItems(),mongoQueries.openOrders()]).then(info => {
                        res.render('openOrders', {pageTitle:'My orders', navBarOn:'1', user:req.user, info:info, refresh:1})
                    }).catch(e => console.log(e))
                }).catch(e => console.log(e))
            }).catch(e => console.log(e))
        }).catch(e => console.log(e))
    }
```

orders.ejs

```
...
<% if(locals.refresh){ %>
  <% if(locals.refresh==1){ %>
      <script>
        setTimeout(location.reload(),5000)
      </script>
  <% } %>
<% } %>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
location.reload() // it reloads page with post data.
```

Try

```
window.location = ""; // opens a page without post data
```

or

```
window.location = document.URL; // opens a current page without post data
```

```
<% if(locals.refresh){ %>
  <% if(locals.refresh==1){ %>
      <script>
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.location = "";
        },5000)
      </script>
  <% } %>
<% } %>
```